# C# CSV Imports Into Listbox With Quotations

Tags: c#, csv, listbox, visual-studio-2015, streamreader

See the below code.  I'm opening a .CSV file and reading it into a listbox, but rather than coming across as -
X
Y
Z
it is 
"X"
"Y"
"Z"

Relevant code is:

```
            if(ofdCSV.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            list.Visible = true;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ofdCSV.FileName);
            string currentLine;
            while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                    list.Items.Add(currentLine);

            }
```

Any ideas?  I've looked around for a while, but I'm still a novice with this, so I'm not entirely sure what to even look for.

Comment: CSV files can commonly be delimited by quotes as well, in order to manage embedded commas that would otherwise be treated as delimiters. Think of the case "Smith, John". Trim the leading and trailing quotes, and you will have your desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV files are a common example of something that is invariably more complex than you think it is at first glance. The process usually starts with you thinking that you know how csv files work and writing some simple code. You then gradually accumulate more and more code as you discover more and more edge cases. The final stage is when all your code is eventually discarded in favor of a 3rd party CSV parser, such as [Filehelpers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers/).

The .net framework has TextFieldParser which does a pretty good job if you set

```
Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
```

A more detailed explanation can be found [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/textfieldparser).
It's less overhead than using a whole other library, but it may fall over if you feed it a line like

> caltrops,"10' pole, 1" diameter",lunch

But you probably don't want to regex that either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Replace` to remove quotes.

```
list.Items.Add(currentLine.Replace('"', '').Trim());
```

or

```
list.Items.Add(currentLine.Replace("\"", string.Empty));;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written following statement which to my knowledge works properly to create CSV data.  The major point here is that CSV data can span multiple lines.  Hope this helps.

```
public static string Escape(string val)
{
    if (val == null)
        return "";

    while (val.EndsWith("\r\n"))
        val = val.Remove(val.Length - 2, 2);

    if (val.Contains("\t"))
        val = val.Replace("\t", "    ");

    if (val.Contains("\r\n"))
        val = val.Replace("\r\n", "\n");

    if (val.Contains("\r"))
        val = val.Replace("\r", "\n");

    if (val.Contains("\""))
        val = val.Replace("\"", "\"\"");

    if (val.Contains(",") ||
        val.Contains("\"") ||
        val.Contains("\n") ||
        val.StartsWith(" ") ||
        val.EndsWith(" "))
    {
        val = "\"" + val + "\"";
    }
    return val;
}
```